# How to build a scikit-learn dataset similar to 20newsgroups

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn

I am just beginning to play with scikit-learning and I have some specific text data which I would like to work with.  Please forgive me up front, but there is much I do not know and the ML terminology alone is proving to be a steep learning curve.

I have followed the 20newsgroups dataset tutorial and my data would be very similar to the Newsgroup structure.

The following commands from a tutorial

```
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian','comp.graphics', 'sci.med']

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

and fetch_20newsgroups yield a dictionary

```
# eg 
dict_keys(['DESCR', 'data', 'target', 'target_names', 'filenames'])
```

So my question is how do I create a my own dataset which is pretty much the same
format as text newsgroups eg

```
news/comp.graphics/file1234
...
news/comp.graphics/file5678
```

my data would be similar

```
eg
myData/targetX/file1
.....
myData/targetX/file2
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that scikit-learn has some tools to build the dataset from the files in each target directory.  I have seen a number of tools to Tokenize, vectorize textual data, but I have not been able to join the dots yet.

Would appreciate any pointers or guidance on how to build my own dataset.

Thank you

I would appreciate it if there were any advice on how to best achieve this.

Comment: Try to work through [the code for `fetch_20newsgroups`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.py#L151) and try to understand it. Maybe you can even adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Look at CountVectorizer, which can get a list of filenames to extract features from. You need to create the labels separately, though. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: Carsten, good suggestion, looking at ....../lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.py is making it clearer. tks